# Ionic Angularfire RecaptchaVerifier: auth/argument-error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angularfire2

I have been trying to implement Phone Number Authentication with my Ionic/Angular project using @angular/fire dependency. I have a service that has the logic for SMS authentication, but when this service is built it generates the following error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error).
FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/argument-error).
    at createErrorInternal (index-e3d5d3f4.js:497:41)
    at _assert (index-e3d5d3f4.js:503:15)
    at new RecaptchaVerifier (index-e3d5d3f4.js:7754:9)
    at new AuthService (auth.service.ts:13:30)
```

This is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Auth,signInWithPhoneNumber,RecaptchaVerifier,signOut} from '@angular/fire/auth';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  recaptchaVerifier: RecaptchaVerifier;

  constructor(private auth: Auth) {
    auth.languageCode ='es';
    this.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {
      size: 'invisible',
      callback: (response: any) => {
        console.log(response + "reCAPTCHA resolved, you can trigger phone number verification here if needed");
      }
    }, this.auth);
  }

  async signInWithPhoneNumber (phoneNumber: string ){
    try {
            const user = await signInWithPhoneNumber(this.auth,phoneNumber,this.recaptchaVerifier);
            return user;
        } catch (e) {
            return null;
        }
  }

    logout() {
        return signOut(this.auth);
    }
}
```

Component HTML:

```
<ion-content class="ion-padding">
  <a (click)="goBack()">&lt; Atrás</a>
  <h3 class="tittle">Ingresa tu número celular</h3>
  <p class="description">Te enviaremos un código para confirmarlo</p>
  <form [formGroup]="phoneForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-input class="margin-top"
        label="Número de celular"
        type="tel"
        class="custom"
        formControlName="phoneNum"
        labelPlacement="floating"
        placeholder="+57 (xxx) xxx-xxxx"
        [maskito]="phoneMask"
        [maskitoElement]="maskPredicate">
      </ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <div id="recaptcha-container"></div>
  <div class="ion-text-center margin-top">
    <ion-button type="submit" *ngIf="phoneForm.valid" fill="outline">Enviar SMS</ion-button>
  </div>
</form>
</ion-content>
```

Component TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MaskitoOptions, MaskitoElementPredicateAsync } from '@maskito/core';
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-phone-method',
  templateUrl: './phone-method.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./phone-method.component.scss'],
})
export class PhoneMethodComponent  implements OnInit {
  phoneForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {
    this.phoneForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      phoneNum: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^\+\d{2}\s\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4}$/)])
    ]});
  }

  submitForm() {
    let phone=this.phoneForm.get('phoneNum')?.value;
    this.authService.signInWithPhoneNumber(phone).then(u=>console.log("confirm: "+u?.confirm+" verificationId: "+u?.verificationId));
    /*let phone=this.phoneForm.get('phoneNum')?.value;
    if (this.phoneForm.valid) {
      console.log(phone);
    }*/
  }

  goBack() {
    // Navigate one step back in the browser's history
    this.router.navigate(['/'])
  }

  readonly phoneMask: MaskitoOptions = {
    mask: ['+','5','7',' ','(',/\d/,/\d/,/\d/,')',' ',/\d/,/\d/,/\d/,'-',/\d/,/\d/,/\d/,/\d/],
  };

  readonly maskPredicate: MaskitoElementPredicateAsync = async (el) => (el as HTMLIonInputElement).getInputElement();

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

What am I missing here?